# Android Alert Dialog box blank white backgroun

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have implemented the BaseActivity pattern in my app and everything works great except when trying to show an Alert Dialog box. This is what happens

[image]

when I try to cancel the dialog box I'm left with this.

[image]

Here's the code for showing the dialog box which resides in the base activity:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Logging out")
                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new 

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            UIUtils.setAnimation(swipeRefreshLayout, true);
                            UserBaas.logoutUser();

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
```

This problem is persistent in an emulator and on an actual device. What could be the issue?

```
switch (item) {
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_HOME:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_MEMOS:
                intent = new Intent(this, MemoGroupActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("section", MemoGroupActivity.MEMO);
                createBackStack(intent);
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_GROUPS:
                intent = new Intent(this, MemoGroupActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("section", MemoGroupActivity.GROUP);
                createBackStack(intent);
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_CONNECTIONS:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, ConnectionsActivity.class));
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_DOCUMENTS:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, DocumentsActivity.class));
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_SETTINGS:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_LOGOUT:
                showLogoutDialog();
                break;
        }
```

And heres the code for UIUtils.setAnimation()

```
public static void setAnimation(SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout, boolean value) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(value);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(value);
    }
```

Comment: so your problem is UserBaas.logoutUser() is not invoked?

Comment: no the problem is that the background is blank and it says blank even after the dialog disappears.

Comment: try in same activity once rather than using BaseActivity.

Comment: i tried implementing the method in the child activities then calling it from the baseactivity but that didnt work

Comment: When the dialog shows, there is nothing in the background, and as u said when u dismiss the alert, you are seeing the same background. It is nothing wrong with the alert dialogue you are showing.  To know more please tell what are you doing in  UIUtils.setAnimation(swipeRefreshLayout, true);
                            UserBaas.logoutUser();

Comment: I've added the code you requested.  UserBaas.logoutUser() starts a background thread so it does no changes to the ui. I'm still tor understand what would cause the white background. Cause even without execution of the code in the buttons the background is already white. In other projects i've done before you can see the activity below the dialog.

Comment: Found the problem. it was this line code `View mainContent = findViewById(R.id.main_content);
            if (mainContent != null) {
                mainContent.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(MAIN_CONTENT_FADEOUT_DURATION);
            }` .Thank you for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

I think parameter Context, you can change this ==> Activity.this (Activity is name of Activity class that you want to show dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 .setNegativeButton(Cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        finish();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(Your_Activity_Name.this);
        b.setTitle("Logging out");
        b.setMessage("Are you sure?");

        b.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // do something
            }
        });

        b.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        b.create().show();
```

Comment: that doesnt work either. i dont think the issue is the dialog but rather how the whole ui is being affected

Comment: Could you please post your full code to see what happened ?

Comment: i have as requested

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.:

```
.setNegativeButton(Cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    dialog.dismiss();
 });
```